# copy data from one table to another using foreign key

Tags: sql

i am facing a problem regarding sql query.

i have a table structure

### TABLE_A

```
A_id : 10,20,30,40 
A_name: a,b,c,d  
B_id: null,null,null,null
```

### TABLE_B

```
B_id: 1,2,3,4  
B_name:n1,n2,n3,n4 
A_id: 10,20,30
```

Now **I need to copy the B_id from TABLE_A to B_id of TABLE_B where A_id of TABLE_A is same as A_id of TABLE_B**

the table will then look like

### TABLE_A

```
A_id : 10,20,30,40  
A_name: a,b,c,d   
B_id: 1,2,3,null
```

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_A 
SET B_id = a.B_id
from TABLE_A a 
WHERE TABLE_A.A_id = a.A_id
```

but its not working and the error is `SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601`

Comment: which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET B_id = b.B_id 
from TABLE_B b 
WHERE TABLE_A.A_id = b.A_id
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, seems to work here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/500c5/2/0

Answer (score 1):

```
update TABLE_A A,TABLE_b B set A.b_id = B.b_id where A.a_id = B.a_id;
```

If you are working on `mysql`. Don't know other database will accept the syntax or not.